# Mongodb - findOneAndDelete() - is not a function

Tags: mongodb, document

My question is about the return message I received.
I wrote this and have the response I was waiting without any problem:

```
db.collection.find({"User.F_Name":"Rose","User.S_Name":"Ring"}).sort({"Contact.Date":-1})
```

But when I will delete the document with:

```
  db.collection.findOneAndDelete({"User.F_Name":"Rose","User.S_Name":"Ring"}).sort({"Contact.Date":-1})
```

The answer is: "...this is not a function"

I don't know where the problem is...

Thanks.

Comment: ...the same... With and without sort (I need sort for delete the first document). I used deleteOne(), deleteMany(), remove(),... The answer is allways that "Contact is not a function"

Comment: see this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: That's not how a "sort" is done with [`findOneAndDelete()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/). In case your MongoDB is actually older than 3.2 then the underlying call is `findAndModify()` anyway, but that has different syntax again.  Look at reference answers and the linked documentation pages. Not also that syntax varies slightly from the "shell" to other driver implementations as well.

Comment: Thanks Neil and Ashish! I used findAndModify() with sort and remove and the result was what I expected!!